# Defined var undefined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am expanding on a tutorial I successfully completed to learn AngularJS (Can be found here: https://github.com/felipedaraujo/saturn-quiz). The app is a quiz about Saturn. I am trying to add the planet Earth as a separate quiz so users can select a quiz based on each planet.

I set up my app that successfully displays a quiz but when I click on a an answer it no longer responds I get a error on the console:

> ```
> angular.js:11655 TypeError: Cannot read property 'questionState' of undefined at ChildScope.$scope.selectAnswer (controllers.js:24)
>
>  at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12404)
>  at callback (angular.js:21566)
>  at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
>  at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:14565)
>  at HTMLParagraphElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21571)
>  at HTMLParagraphElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3032)
>
> (anonymous) @ angular.js:11655
>
> (anonymous) @ angular.js:8596
>
> $apply @ angular.js:14567
>
> (anonymous) @ angular.js:21571
>
> eventHandler @ angular.js:3032
> ```

For reference I will include the code for the three HTML pages and the controllers.js code

I also have a Plunker with the file structure that gives more insight on the file structure. (The Plunker doesn't display anything I'm not sure if it's Plunke or I did something wrong).: https://plnkr.co/edit/vWSVFZyxdYcnynSCH7IB?p=info

**HTML - index.html**

```
<body class="disable-select">

    <div class="main" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**HTML - list.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Planet Quizzes</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 cf" ng-repeat="item in quizzes">
    <a href="#/details/{{ quizzes.indexOf(item) }}">
      {{ item.questionType }}
    </a>
  </div>
</div><!-- END ROW -->
```

**HTML details.html**

```
 <div id="myQuiz" class="container-fluid" ng-model="quizzess">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Test Your Knowledge: <span>{{quizzes[whichItem].questionType}}</span> </h1> 
    </div>
  </div><!-- END ROW -->

  <div class="progress">  
    <div class="{{ ($index === activeQuestion) ? 'on' : 'off' }} 
        {{ (quizzes.questionState === 'answered') ? 'answered' : 'unanswered' }}
        {{ (quizzes.correctness === 'correct') ? 'correct' : 'incorrect' }}" 
      ng-repeat="quiz in quizzes">
    </div>
  </div><!-- END PROGRESS BAR -->

<div class="intro {{ (activeQuestion > -1) ? 'inactive' : 'active' }}"> 
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>Click to begin to test your knowledge of Saturn.</p>
    <p class="btn" ng-click="activeQuestion = 0">Begin</p>
</div> <!-- END INTRO -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="question 
        {{ $index === activeQuestion ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}
        {{ quizzes.questionState === 'answered' ? 'answered' : 'unanswered' }} col-xs-10">
      <p class="txt">{{ quizzes[whichItem].question }}</p>
      <p class="ans" 
        ng-click="selectAnswer($parent.$index, $index)" 
        ng-repeat="Answer in quizzes[whichItem].answers">{{ Answer.text }}</p>

      <div class="feedback">
        <p ng-show="quizzes.correctness === 'correct'"><strong>Correct</strong>.</p>
        <p ng-show="quizzes.correctness === 'incorrect'">Oops! That is not correct.</p>
        <p> {{ quizzes.feedback }} </p>
        <div class="btn" ng-click="selectContinue()">Continue</div>
      </div>
      <!-- END FEEDBACK -->
    </div><!-- END QUESTION -->
  </div><!-- END ROW -->
```

**JS - controllers.js**

```
var quizListControllers = angular.module('quizListControllers', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize']);

quizListControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.quizzes = data;
    $scope.quizOrder = 'name';
  });
}]);

quizListControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $sce){
    $scope.score = 0;
    // $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
    $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
    $scope.percentage = 0;

    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.quizzes = data;
      $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
      $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.quizzes.length; 
    });

    $scope.selectAnswer = function(qIndex,aIndex){

      var questionState = $scope.quizzes[qIndex].questionState;

      if(questionState != 'answered') {
        $scope.quizzes[qIndex].selectedAnswer = aIndex;
        var correctAnswer = $scope.quizzes[qIndex].correct;

        $scope.quizzes[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer;

        if(aIndex === correctAnswer){
          $scope.quizzes[qIndex].correctness = 'correct';
          $scope.score += 1;
        }
        else{
          $scope.quizzes[qIndex].correctness = 'incorrect';
        }

        $scope.quizzes[qIndex].questionState = 'answered';
      }

      $scope.percentage = (($scope.score / $scope.totalQuestions) * 100).toFixed(1);
    }

    $scope.isSelected = function(qIndex,aIndex){
      return $scope.quizzes[qIndex].selectedAnswer === aIndex;
    }

    $scope.isCorrect = function(qIndex,aIndex){
      return $scope.quizzes[qIndex].correctAnswer === aIndex;
    }

    $scope.selectContinue = function(){
      return $scope.activeQuestion += 1;
    }

}]);
```

I believe it has something to do with the ng-click in the question div but this is the code from the original tutorial and worked with the original file structure (can be found in the Github link above or [here](https://github.com/felipedaraujo/saturn-quiz)). Perhaps something changed, but I can't figure it out. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Try to use `ng-click="selectAnswer(whichItem, $index)" `

Comment: So `$scope.quizzes` appears to be an array (for example `$scope.quizzes[qIndex].questionState`) yet your template attempts to access `quizzes.questionState`. You probably meant `quiz.questionState` given you're using `ng-repeat="quiz in quizzes"`

Comment: Thank you both, both of your answers have contributed to helping me understand my code a bit better and get closer to a solution. After adding your changes I no longer the error. I have ammended my question to include a div with a class of "intro" in the details.html. This sets the activeQuestion to 0 which begins the quiz. The progress bar updates to show it's on the first question but the div containing the question does not switch from inactive to active. If I manually change it in the DOM it shows but when I answer the question it does not switch from unanswered to answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing instances of [whichItem] with [$index] in the details.html file and changing this line in the Controller.js worked:

```
 $scope.activeQuestion = -2; //uncommented and changed from -1 to -2
```